# Get return value of method from api explorer endpoint android

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, android-asynctask, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to get the return of my method that I call from my android endpoint.

Here is my method that test if there is already an user in the entity NewUsers on google explorer api (the method works fine when I test it on explorer api) :

```
/**
 * Method to update the information about the user.
 * We don't allow to update the email.
 * @param : String email (to compare), String sexe, String age, String weight,
 * @return : JSONObject containing the response
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "greetings.userExist", httpMethod = "get", path = "jsonobject/userExist")
public JSONObject userExist(@Named("Email") String email) {

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("Value", "false");  

    Query q = new Query ("NewUsers");
    q.addFilter("Email", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, email);

    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);        

    for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable ())
    {
        // = user already exist
        if(entity.getProperty("Email").equals(email)){
            obj.put("Value", "true");       
        }       
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And here is the code from my client endpoint android (**EDITED**) :

```
// Get the jsonObject to know if the user already exist
    userExist = new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>() {

        JSONObject jsonObject;

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Retrieve service handle.
            Helloworld apiServiceHandle = AppConstants.getApiServiceHandle();

            try {
                // Call the api method and pass the value
                return (JSONObject) apiServiceHandle.greetings().userExist(emailUser).getJsonContent();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj) {
            Log.i("Value :",obj.toString());
            if(obj != null){
                try {
                    value = obj.getString("Value");
                    Log.i("Value :", value);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    };

    userExist.execute();
```

When I print the result is null..

How can I get the all jsonObject?

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a JsonObject , i would suggest you to **create a separate class**,which would contain all the required fields .Make sure this class is **Serializable** and just put the object in output.
You will find the object in response.